# Include headers with one level indirection?

Tags: c++, cmake, header, sdl

To include the SDL2 library in my project using CMake on Windows a did this :

```
target_include_directories(main_receiver PRIVATE "D:/Programs/SDL2-2.0.9/include")
target_link_libraries(main_receiver "D:/Programs/SDL2-2.0.9/lib/x64/SDL2.lib")
```

I can now include every header file in D:/Programs/SDL2-2.0.9/include directly :

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_audio.h>
#include <SDL_bits.h>
#include <SDL_assert.h>
. . .
```

However in the Vulkan templates (the Vulkan SDK includes the third party SDL2 library) all includes for SDL2 are done like this :

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_audio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_bits.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_assert.h>
. . .
```

How can I use the latter mode/style ?

I like it more because it reduces naming conflicts and it also helps in distinguishing that I am using SDL2 version of the library.

Comment: Does this not work?

Comment: Maybe you need to change `"D:/Programs/SDL2-2.0.9/include"` to `"D:/Programs/SDL2-2.0.9/include/SDL2"` although if the SDL headers use the `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` convention you will want to keep both folders in your includes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so drescherjm comment was close.

Simply put all header files in a folder named SDL2 inside the /include directory and now you can use the second method of header includes :

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```